# Клиент передает серверу две даты, а сервер возвращает количество лет между датами

Tags: java, java-ee

Как правильно передать дату, не возвращает количество лет

Код сервера

```
 `package s;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.time.*;
    import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
    import java.util.Date;
public class S {


    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
            System.out.println("Welcome to Server side");
        BufferedReader in = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;

        ServerSocket servers = null;
        Socket fromclient = null;

        try {
            servers = new ServerSocket(4444);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't listen to port");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        try {
            System.out.print("Waiting for a client...");
            fromclient = servers.accept();
            System.out.println("Client connected");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Can't accept");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fromclient.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(fromclient.getOutputStream(), true);
        String input, input1;

        System.out.println("Waiting for messages");
                while ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    input1 = in.readLine();
            String[] words = null;
            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
                break;
            else if (input.trim().length() == 0) {
                words = new String[0];
            } else {
                words = input.trim().split("[ ,.!?:;]+");
                               DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
LocalDate fuser = LocalDate.parse(in.readLine(), formatter);
LocalDate fuser1 = LocalDate.parse(in.readLine(), formatter);
Period period = Period.between(fuser, fuser1);
                System.out.println("Получено: " + input);
                                System.out.println("Получено: " + input1);
                           out.println("Server :ЛЕТ: " +period.getYears());
            }
            System.out.println(input.length());

        }


        out.close();
        in.close();
        fromclient.close();
        servers.close();

    }

}`
```

Код клиента

```
 package c;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class C {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        System.out.print("Welcome to Client side\nInput IP to connect:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ip = sc.nextLine();// если сервер и клиент на одном пк, то вводить localhost или 127.0.0.1

        Socket fromserver = null;
        fromserver = new Socket(ip, 4444);
        System.out.println("Connected to " + ip);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fromserver.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fromserver.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader inu = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String fuser, fuser1, fserver;

        while ((fuser = inu.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println(fuser);
                       fuser1 = inu.readLine();
            out.println(fuser1);
                        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");

                       fserver = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(fserver);
            if (fuser.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
                break;
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
        inu.close();
        fromserver.close();
        sc.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Это реальный код? В нем синтаксическая ошибка, на него должна ругаться любая IDE. Отформатируйте нормально и ошибка станет видна невооруженным глазом.

Comment: Зачем Вы удалили весь код из своего вопроса?

Answer (score 1):

Сервер ожидает три строки: не пустую и не равную "exit" и две строки с датами.
Клиент присылает только две строки с датами.